# Draw a border around a part of NSAttributedString

Tags: macos, cocoa, draw, core-text, nsattributedstring

I'm developing a MacOs application and have to implement my own search functional due to custom interface.

So the question is - how can a draw a border around a part of NSAttributedString in NSTextView to display search result (just how it's done in TextEdit app). Please check the desired look on the attached image:

http://d.pr/i/w8wP

**[UPDATE]**

Due to custom interface requirements I can't use NSTextViews's `setUsesFindBar:` and `setUsesFindPanel:`. The interface has a custom NSSearchField, which should perform search in a textView.

I've got familiar with `performTextFinderAction:`, but how do I trigger it on a textView with the NSSearchField value?

Answer (score 2):

For what you want to do you need not use the IB or any find operation, because an `NSTextView` object (let's say its name is `myTextView`) does it all. You have to first create a range of characters you want to highlight and then tell `myTextView` to do it:

```
NSRange charRange = NSMakeRange( location length );   // whatever you want
[myTextView showFindIndicatorForRange:charRange];
```

If the selection is within a `NSScrollView` this selection should be made visible. Do this before you call `-showFindIndicatorForRange` (see the doc under `NSTextView`):

```
NSLayoutManager *layout = [myTextView layoutManager];
NSRect rect = [layout boundingRectForGlyphRange:charRange
                                inTextContainer:[myTextView textContainer] ];
[myTextView scrollRectToVisible:rect];
```

And now an extension to show as many highlighted strings as you want. Let us assume we want to mark all characters at a prime number position. (I do not know what that shall be good for, but why not?). We create an NSArray with the corresponding ranges: (**pseudocode**!, the ranges must be NSValues! )

```
allRanges = { (1,1) (2,1) (3,1) (5,1) (7,1) etc.}
```

All can now be selected together:

```
[myTextView setSelectedRanges:allRanges];
// select the 3th (zero based) entry
[showFindIndicatorForRange:[allRanges objectAtIndex:3];
```

This is used within the find mechanism, but it also works without using any finding process.

Comment: I already use substring ranges for showing findIndicator. If we perform `setSelectedRanges:`, the selected ranges get grey background. Now let's imagine, that my text already has grey background, like in this image http://d.pr/i/K7be. So after I search for 'a' symbol, all text remains grey. And what I want to accomplish is to have white rectangles around search terms, like it's done in TextEdit.

Answer (score 0):

In interface builder, you can set the "Find" property to control where the built in find/replace bar is displayed. To do a find action in code, invoke `performFindPanelAction:` on the NSTextView.

Comment: Thank you, perhaps that's what I need. But could you please justify, how can this be accoplished by code as I don't use IB in my project.

Comment: There are two methods `setUsesFindBar:` and `setUsesFindPanel:` which you can set appropriately to your implementation.

Comment: The answer is still use performFindPanelAction:

Comment: `performFindPanelAction:` only takes senders tag as a parameter to define the kind of operation to be performed. How can I make NSSearchField's value to be found in the text? As I stated earlier - the search field does not belong to a find bar or find panel.

Comment: NSTextFinder is the mediating controller from a search field to the text view.