# How to add box around NSString inside NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nstextview

I'm working on a **OS X application** and I'm pretty much stuck at this.
I have some text inside `NSTextView` and I would like to put box around some strings (I have ranges for those substrings).

Any ideas?

Also, perfect solution would be to create something similar that Xcode has, when you type for example `[NSString stringWithFormat: (NSString *), ..)];` Screenshot: 
[image: Autocomplete suggestions]

I'm interested in that blue box which suggests what type is expected.
Any help would be really appreciated!

This question is not entirely related to possible duplicate question, since they are working on iOS application with slightly different approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSAttributedString background color and rounded corners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362407/nsattributedstring-background-color-and-rounded-corners)

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607551/draw-a-border-around-a-part-of-nsattributedstring) help?

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks, but that is yellow effect to show which words were found. I already use that for showing some unsolved variables in my app. But thanks for effort! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that *Xcode* achieves these effects using [NSTextAttachment](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextAttachment_Class/index.html) objects embedded within [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html) instances. (The same sort of effect can be seen in their `NSTokenField` control, which definitely uses this approach).

[image]

It's a pretty big topic though: you need to be proficient with attributed strings, text attachments, the [NSTextAttachmentCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTextAttachmentCell_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSTextAttachmentCell) class and a few other bits and pieces from Cocoa's text architecture. The job is made all the more difficult by the fact that there's very little documentation (official or unoffical) for doing this sort of thing.

Comment: Now that's the answer I was looking for! I thought it wouldn't be so easy, but that is a quite overkill for me. Anyway, thanks, will definitely check that out!